# Error while running powershell script

Tags: powershell

I want to remove bak files after zip from all subfolder for given path, so all duplicate files with extension .bak will be removed,i run below script but getting error.

```
$filePath = "d:\Test\"

$Afiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".bak"}
$Bfiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".7z"}

$Alist = @()
$Blist = @()

foreach( $A in $Afiles) {
    $Alist += $A.baseName
}

foreach( $B in $Bfiles) {
    $Blist += $B.baseName
}

foreach($A in $Alist) {
    if($Blist -contains $a) 
    {
        rm ("$A.bak") 
    }
}
```

I am receiving below error :

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\******\Desktop\master_backup_2015_08_21_013722_8370267.bak' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\*****\Desktop\duplicatedelete1.ps1:26 char:10
+        rm <<<<  ("$A.bak") 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\****....722_8370267.bak:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're receiving error because you're not specifying full path for `rm` command and PowerShell tries to delete file in your current directory.

Try this:

```bsh
$Path = 'D:\Test'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Filter '*.7z' | ForEach-Object {
    $BackupFile = Join-Path -Path (Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent) -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + '.bak')
    if(Test-Path -Path $BackupFile){
        Remove-Item -Path $BackupFile
    }
}
```

Comment: It still gives error as below :

Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'D:\Test\AdventureWorks2012_backup_2015_08_21_013722_9618283.bak' because it does not exist.
At line:26 char:10
+        rm <<<<  (Join-Path $filePath -ChildPath "$A.bak")
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Test\Adventu...722_9618283.bak:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: path is "D:\Test"..now files are in subfolder1,subfolder2 in Test folder,,but as per script it tries to delete .bak file from d:\Test\filename path..where it dont find it.what is wrong in query?

Comment: query should go to delete the file in subfolder of Test folder...but why after getting file name it tries to delete it from the parent folder only?

Comment: @Mehul, sorry, forgot about `-Recurse` switch. Try the new script, it should work now.